# How does TCP relate to a wire-level protocol?

Tags: tcp, bittorrent

This is how I always imagined TCP to be related to an Application:
[Linke to image because I can't embed it (reputation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkqQc.png)

Now I try to understand the Peer Wire Protocol [as described here](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Peer_wire_protocol_.28TCP.29) and there is talk of headers, and it is specified as "TCP". So is the graphic above still valid? Or does this part of the BitTorrent Protocol somehow replace the TCP-Software? 
Thanks!

Comment: I think I understood it now: TCP is a standard and there are different implementations. In the case of BitTorrent, the BitTorrent client takes over the whole tcp-software part, and there is no 3rd party tcp program.

Answer (score 0):

> In computer networking, a wire protocol refers to a way of getting
>   data from point to point: A wire protocol is needed if more than one
>   application has to interoperate.[1] In contrast to transport protocols
>   at the transport level (like TCP or UDP), the term 'wire protocol' is
>   used to describe a common way to represent information at the
>   application level.

This protocol is on the application level. But it is designed to work with TCP, since here package transmission is ensured (i.e. alle packages are acutally delivered, and in the right order).

UDP is less relieable, so there was Micro Transport Protocol (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Transport_Protocol) designed for it.